# mySQL Auto increment using JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have created a page and want to store it in mySQl but i want to implement autoincrement from my java program and pass it as a parameter.how to get that.I used static count=0 counter as passing but it is not happening.
This is the function i am using

```
static int=count++;
CorruptionStory corruptionStory = 
    new CorruptionStory(count, new State(stateId,stateNameSelected), 
                        age, new Department(deptId,departmentNameSelected), 
                        positionOfOfficial,bribeAmount, description, sqlDate);
isSuccessfullySaved = CorruptionStoryJdbcImpl.
                          saveCorruptionStory(corruptionStory);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to have the java code manage the auto incrementing of the number, you should really configure your table schema to do it for you.  Here is why:

1. if you restart your application, you will need to write code to figure out what number to resume with.
2. if you have multiple instances of your program running, they will somehow need to coordinate with each other so they don't use the same number.

MySQL column definitions allow you to specify auto-increment, see this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html

it would be much better if you wrote a SQL schema file to solve this problem.  Then, when you do the insert statement from the java program, you can omit that column, and MySQL will automatically set it to the next appropriate value.

Also, if you are willing to spend time studying hibernate, you can use that.  Hibernate is able to generate your SQL schema automatically for you, and even update the database for you at startup.  It has an annotation that lets you tell hibernate that a certain class field (table column) should be an automatically incrementing id.

I should warn you though, hibernate is not something you're going to learn overnight.